# How can I move data from a azure TABLESTORAGE tproduction table to a development table?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I've set up two different tables with two connection strings. Now I want to move data from one to the other but I'm not sure where to start. Has anyone else coded up some solution for this. If so I would really appreciate some tips/advice on where to start. My tablestorage tables are small. Some are around 500-2000 rows. I would just like to make sure that data does not get lost.

Please note it is tablestorage that I am using and NOT Sql Azure

Thanks if you have some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with only a few thousand rows then this is easy.

Download TableXplorer here: http://clumsyleaf.com/products/tablexplorer

There is an option to export all data from a table to an XML or CSV file. Once you have your file then use the import option with the file and import it into the other table.